# Create folder name via Set command issue

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a simple .BAT file that creates a folder with a name, based on what the user enters. My problem is, is that when the user enters more than 1 word, it creates a folder for every word.
I want a solution that:

1. Allows the user to create multiple words and will only create one folder with the full name
2. Allows the user to only use one word by using some kind of checking mechanism, so it will create only one folder with one word. It will not accept multiple words.

Below is the line I use to create the foldername:

```
**set /p x= Enter a SINGLE WORD to name the new folder:**
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to quote the folder name `md "%x%"` ?

Comment: thanks MC ND ... yes, I did!

Comment: Show how you create the folder...

Comment: You're not really working under DOS, do you?

Comment: No, I am not working under DOS. It is W7's DOS Emulator

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** - See all the words as only one folder name

```
set /p "x=folder name?"
md "%x%"
```

The quotes will avoid the splitting of the folder name

**Option 2** - Only use the first word as folder name

```
set /p "x=folder name?"
for /f %%a in ("%x%") do md "%%a"
```

The `for /f` command will only retrieve the first token (can be customized, but by default, only first token, with input string splitted using spaces and tabs as delimiters)

Comment: So for every name entered, my script should make a folder and in that folder, a textfile with the contents of what's in it. It is part of a larger script. I used option 1 from MC ND and now a single directory will be created if the user enters multiple words, but now the textfile will not appear inside the folder ! When I enter one word, it still works just fine.

Comment: The script:

    set /p "x= Enter a name for the new backup folder: " echo. echo Enter a comment about the contents. echo. md "%x%" set Output="%x%" set /p y=Comment description: echo This folder contains: %y% >> "%Output%\Contents of "%x%.txt"

Comment: @John, `md "%x%"`, `...`, `echo This folder contains %y% > "%x%\contents of %x%.txt"` Better don't include quotes in variable data, just add them in the correct place in the commands

Comment: for some reason or the other, if I quote the script in this comments field, it gets all messy, just like my previous post. Anyways, I still get that text file outside the folder. Can't seem to fix that, it looks like...